# Would it be OK to reference the existence of my LaTeX book in my name on this site?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently running a kickstarter for my LaTeX book. I was thinking that I might change my display name to something like "Don Hosek—author of The Preppy Lion: An Author's Guide to LaTeX" but I don't want to be gauche either, so if there's *any* objection, I won't do it.

Comment: It's so sad that you have to ask permission for this. However, in my experience, as long as you don't promote sites that compete with this, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @DonHosek Do you think it's "so sad" or did you feel you "have to ask"? One of our moderators asked such a question to our community already here: [Promotional material in usernames](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8616/) Technically it may be a duplicate, but the other generic thread soon focused on putting web site URLs in names for promotion (that escalated quickly), so I gladly added an opinion here as well. I hope it helped. Btw. the technical character limit for names is 30, the text in the question has 63 chars.

Comment: I just applied for the PDF version! :)

Answer (score 7):

You could add your book name with cover and description to your profile text and also add a link.

You could even use your kickstarter campaign URL as your homepage link.

You could write a blog post on https://tex-talk.net (formerly it was https://tex.blogoverflow.com as TeX.SE blog). I could build and host a book website for you, similar https://latex-cookbook.net including on-page-compiling of sample codes. (I was too lazy to add that book to my profile, but did it for my first book.)

I'd be glad to help in supporting and promoting like above. In my opinion, advertisement in a user name may not be a good choice. A bad sample name to get a feeling: "Jonny—author of Buy Bitcoin" as author of some hundreds of answers or chat messages. Sorry for that :-) it's Jonny not you. And your book is on-topic. Book promotion and kickstarter promotion is good, user names are user names.

Also Twitter announcements of start or progress may be good, such as this one that I made right now:

https://twitter.com/TeXgallery/status/1411376621223809030

[image: Preppy Lion Tweet]

Comment: I have a link in my profile for the kickstarter and the existing book page, but thanks for the offer. I will write something up for tex-talk though,

Comment: @DonHosek On the "About" page you can find a contact email address. Further options are announcements or other posts on some of the sites at [LaTeX.net](https://latex.net/about/).

Comment: @DonHosek Congratulations for reaching the goal!